# Why won't my php website display on localhost?

Tags: php, apache2

I am very very new to php. I have a simple "test.php" file in my Documents/PHP/ directory. I go to "localhost/test.php" but I get a:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I installed php using these commands:

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

and

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

here is the contents of my "test.php" file:

```
<?php 
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Did you configure Apache to point at `Documents/PHP` in its configuration?

Comment: No I did not. How would you do that? and what is it pointed at by default?

Comment: In the browser, assuming apache is running, what do you get if you run: `http://locahost/` with a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document root path for web files should be in **/var/www/html** for apache2 by default